# Check if username doesn't exists

Tags: php, users, updates

I have a script that imports users via an .csv file.
The script checks if a user exists and if so updates it's metadata.
If the user does exists but the "status" field contains the word 'archived' it should delete the user.
If none of the above is true it's a new user and gets added to the userlist.

So the script is like this:

```
foreach ($data as $gebruiker){
    $username = $gebruiker['username'];
    if ( username_exists( $username ) && $gebruiker['status'] == 'published' ){
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username);
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'import_1', $gebruiker['email'] );
    }elseif(username_exists( $username ) && $gebruiker['status'] == 'archived'){
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username);
        wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
    }else{
        $users = wp_insert_user(
        array( 
        'user_login'    =>  $gebruiker['username'],
        'user_pass'     =>  $gebruiker['password'],
        'first_name'    =>  $gebruiker['first_name'],
        'last_name'     =>  $gebruiker['last_name'],
        'user_email'    =>  $gebruiker['email'],
        'display_name'  =>  $gebruiker['first_name'] . ' ' . $gebruiker['last_name'],
        'nickname'      =>  $gebruiker['first_name'] . '' . $gebruiker['last_name'],
        'role'          =>  'subscriber'
        )                       
    );
    foreach ($data as $update_user) {
        update_user_meta( $users, 'import_1', $update_user['first_name'] );
        update_user_meta( $users, 'import_2', $update_user['last_name'] );
        update_user_meta( $users, 'status', 'published' );
    }
}
```

The thing is that I don't know how to check if a user doesn't exists.
 Because the way it is now the user get's deleted and then added again.

Logically I should first check if the user exists and then update it's data.
after that I should add the user if he doesn't exists
final I should delete all the users who have a status `archived`.

How can I do something like: 
`if ( ! username_exists( $username ) )`

Comment: Actually you know the answer. To check if username doesn't exist you have to do `if ( ! username_exists( $username ) )`. Can you elaborate what your problem is a little more? As it is, it seems that your problem is about logical conditions and not about how to check if username exists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it fixed. Pretty simple actually.

I moved the if part where the user get's deleted to the bottom of the script.

```
foreach ($data as $gebruiker){
    $username = $gebruiker['username'];
    if ( username_exists( $username ) && $gebruiker['status'] == 'published' ){
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username);
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'import_1', $gebruiker['email'] );
    }else{
        $users = wp_insert_user(
        array( 
            'user_login'    =>  $gebruiker['username'],
            'user_pass'     =>  $gebruiker['password'],
            'first_name'    =>  $gebruiker['first_name'],
            'last_name'     =>  $gebruiker['last_name'],
            'user_email'    =>  $gebruiker['email'],
            'display_name'  =>  $gebruiker['first_name'] . ' ' . $gebruiker['last_name'],
            'nickname'      =>  $gebruiker['first_name'] . '' . $gebruiker['last_name'],
            'role'          =>  'subscriber'
             )                      
        );
        foreach ($data as $update_user) {
            update_user_meta( $users, 'import_1', $update_user['first_name'] );
            update_user_meta( $users, 'import_2', $update_user['last_name'] );
        }
    }if(username_exists( $username ) && $gebruiker['status'] == 'archived'){
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username);
        wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
    }
```

Comment: With this code you can have situations where a new user is inserted and then deleted, which is a waste of resources. You should think again in the logic you are following.

Comment: I see your point! Any ideas? Maybe I can only import the people who have a status`published` but the next time the import runs they won't be deleted if their new status is`archived`